# conductor and its properties

Tags: semiconductors

The conductivity of material A is half that of material B. The  ratio of relaxation time of A to that of B is?

As far as I know conductivity is proportional to relaxation time. so the answer should be 0.5, but the answer is 2. please explain?

Am I missing anything here?

And one more question:

when a temperature of conductor is approaching zero kelvin, the mean free path of free electrons in the conductor is proportional to ?

how is it proportional to collision or relaxation time?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so you are asking why lower conductivity means a higher relaxation time. You expected it to be the other way around.

Picture yourself trying to get across a crowded room. If everyone is holding still, you will be able to get across quickly. If everyone is moving around, you'll get bounced around and have trouble getting across.

This is also true if you happen to be an electron. Conductivity is better if all the other electrons are holding still. So, this is why lower temperature leads to higher current.

Relaxation time is better if all the electrons aren't bouncing all over the place--they can all walk back to their "places" more quickly because they're not interfering so much with each other. (And you can think of impurities etc that would increase relaxation time as a bunch of furniture in the room that they have to move around).